# Setting progress bar color to default prior to API 21

Tags: android

I want to be able to set the color of a progress bar so that users can easily determine if the bar is indicating completion or almost completed. This is illustrated in the screenshot below and works fine in Lollipop (API 21).

[image]

The code that works is

```
private void initializeOriginalStyles(View view) {
    if (!mOriginalStylesSet) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.personEventProgressBar);
            if (progressBar != null) {
                mProgressBarColour = progressBar.getProgressDrawable().getColorFilter();
            }
        }
        mOriginalStylesSet = true;
    }
}
```

and in the Adapter.bindView() I set the progress drawable like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    if (numSkillsInLevelForEvent == numSkillsCompletedInLevel) {
            progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.pass_level), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    } else {
            progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(mProgressBarColour);
    }
}
```

This is because in APi 21 we have access to [Drawable.getColorFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getColorFilter()) and so I can capture the original color filter and set it when progress is not completed.

Setting the color is no problem because [Drawable.setColorFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter(int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)) has been available since API 1.  This means prior to API 21 I can set it to my color which indicates completion but don't know what to set it back to.

Trying to work around this API limitation I have tried setting the progress bar drawable and calling [Drawable.mutate()](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html) before setting the color to my custom color which indicates completion. Unfortunately this does not work as expected and the color for all progress bars is tinted to the completion color which means that the attribute is shared amongst all progress bars and that mutate isn't doing what I expect.

Here is the code where I try to capture the original progress bar drawable

```
private void initializeOriginalStyles(View view) {
    if (!mOriginalStylesSet) {
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.personEventProgressBar);
        if(progressBar != null) {
            mProgressBarDrawable = progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
        }
        mOriginalStylesSet = true;
    }
}
```

and in the Adapter.bindView() method I try to set the progress drawable like this

```
if(numSkillsInLevelForEvent == numSkillsCompletedInLevel) {
        Drawable completedProgressBar = mProgressBarDrawable.mutate();
        completedProgressBar.setColorFilter(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.pass_level), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        progressBar.setProgressDrawable(completedProgressBar);
    } else {
        progressBar.setProgressDrawable(mProgressBarDrawable);
}
```

This all results in the progress bars all being set to the completed color

[image]

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?
Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation for `Drawable.mutate()`. It returns the same drawable object that it was called on, not a clone. Have you tried just setting the color filter to `null` when you don't need it to be specially tinted?

Comment: I saw that the documentation said the properties of the drawable would not be shared after calling Drawable.mutate().  Setting the color filter to null seems to work, I was hesitant to hardcode it to anything because that is less future friendly but in this case since I can offer functionality to a greater range of versions I'll go with it for now.  Thanks alanv!